# How do I create features in featuretools for rows with the same id and a time index?

Tags: python, data-science, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

I have a Dataframe like this

```
data = {'Customer':['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3', 'C3'],
        'NumOfItems':[3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 10, 6, 14],
        'PurchaseTime':["2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03","2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03","2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03"]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want to create a Feature which is for example the max value for each customer up to this point:

```
'MaxPerID(NumOfItems)':[3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 10, 10, 14] #the output i want
```

So I set up the EntitySet and normalize it …

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id="customer_data")
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="customer",
                              dataframe=df,
                              index='index',
                              time_index="PurchaseTime",
                             make_index=True)

es = es.normalize_entity(base_entity_id="customer",
                         new_entity_id="sessions",
                         index="Customer")
```

But creating the feature matrix doesn't produce the results i want.

```
feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                 target_entity="customer",
                                 agg_primitives = ["max"],
                                 max_depth = 3                                      
                                 )
feature_matrix.head

sessions.MAX(customer.NumOfItems)  
index                                                                         
0                                      4                                    
3                                      6                                    
6                                     14                                    
1                                      4                                    
4                                      6                                    
7                                     14                                    
2                                      4                                    
5                                      6                                    
8                                     14
```

The returned feature is the max value per day from **all** customers (sorted by time), however if I run the same code without the `time_index = "PurchaseTime"` the result is the max value just for the specific customer

```
    sessions.MAX(customer.NumOfItems)  \
index                                                                       
0                    4   
1                    4   
2                    4   
3                    6   
4                    6   
5                    6   
6                   14   
7                   14   
8                   14
```

I want a combination of these two: the max value for the specific customer up to this point.
Is this possible? I tried to work with `es['customer']['Customer'].interesting_values =['C1', 'C2', 'C3']` but it didn't get me anywhere. I also tried modifying the new normalized entity and writing my own primitive for this.

I'm new to featuretools so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[This Question is similar to mine but the solution has no time_index and is creating the new features on the normalized entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216200/how-to-create-new-variables-by-multiple-ids-in-featuretools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question. You can get the expected output by using a group by transform primitive.

```py
fm, fd = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity="customer",
    groupby_trans_primitives=['cum_max'],
)
```

You should get the cumulative max of the number of items per customer.

```py
column = 'CUM_MAX(NumOfItems) by Customer'
actual = fm[[column]].sort_values(column)
expected = {'MaxPerID(NumOfItems)': [3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 10, 10, 14]}
actual.assign(**expected)
```

```
       CUM_MAX(NumOfItems) by Customer  MaxPerID(NumOfItems)
index
0                                  3.0                     3
1                                  3.0                     3
2                                  4.0                     4
3                                  5.0                     5
4                                  5.0                     5
5                                  6.0                     6
6                                 10.0                    10
7                                 10.0                    10
8                                 14.0                    14
```